# Проблема с аудивыходом на ноутбуке с Ubuntu 16.04 (SOLVED)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, аудио, драйвер

У меня есть ноут Dell Vostro 5471 с установленной Ubuntu 16.04. 
У ноутбука аудивыход совмещен с аудиовходом.
До вчерашнего дня после того как я вставлял джек в ноут у меня выскакивало диалоговое окно которое спрашивало в каком режиме я хочу использовать аудиовход/выход (только выход, гарнитура, микрофон). Но сегодня внезапно спрашивать перестало. После того как я вставляю джек, продолжают работать встроенные в ноутбук динамики. Поставил утилиту pavucontrol которая позволяет в ручном режиме переключать аудиорежим (встроенные динамики или внешние). Вопрос - как мне вернуться к старой схеме, когда линукс меня спрашивал?

PS
Собственно вся проблема оказалась в грязи попавшей в разъем

Comment: Есть две версии произошедшего: 1) вы обновили ядро, там поломали т.н. Jack Sense; 2) просто поломался разъём, контакт отвадился, и ядро не видит событий. (В первый вариант ещё вписывается обновление BIOS, но это весьма маловероятно. В Windows так и работает?)

Comment: Собственно я уже разобрался, туда попала грязь из за чего он перестал срабатывать как надо...